# Python Vs C multithreading CPU utilization

Tags: python, c, multithreading, gil

I am toying with simple multi-threading program in both Python and C, where main starts multiple threads in a for loop and thread just do while(1). For both cases I ran 20 threads and observed CPU Utilization using 'top' with following outcomes:-

1. C: 99.9% Userspace, 0% SysSpace
2. Python: 11.3% Userspace, 10.7 SysSpace

Specs: 12 Core i7 8thGen. 16GB Ram

It would be great if someone can comment on why this is happening? Specially commenting on the way python and C execution works. Thank.

Comment: Do you build the C code with optimizations enabled? Any benchmarking without optimizations is really pointless. Also, are you sure that the code in both languages are doing the ***exact*** same thing? Even the slightest deviation could lead to big differences.

Comment: Without seeing the test programs this is hard to say.

Comment: A `while 1: pass` in CPython is not executed *in parallel* - the global interpreter lock ensures that only *one* of the cores can be executing the Python bytecode ceval loop at any given time.

Furthermore, Python bytecode interpreter will voluntarily yield to other threads after a certain number of instructions if there are other threads in *ready* state. This will mean a context switch through kernel, which is the reason for the big system space load.

Comment: Thank you @AnttiHaapala. Attached answers helped.